# Clarification about big Oh calculation

Tags: asymptotics

Say you have a loop that iterates over an array,

```
for i in someArray:
    //some code
```

This basic example would have a running time of $O(n)$. Say that you added a nested loop with equal number of operations, this then would be $O(n^2)$. My question is, is it safe to do this kind of simplication in general? For example,

Say your outer loop had worst case complexity of $O(n^2)$ and your inner loop has worst case complexity of $O(\log n)$. Can the total time complexity be said as $O(n^2\log n)$?

Comment: Note that the outer loop *subsumes* (a multiple of) the runtime of the inner loop. Where does the logarithmic factor go? Is your language off?

Comment: @Raphael I don't understand your question, can you clarify?

Comment: You talk about the "complexity" of the outer loop as if it would not contain the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Big O is all about the upper bound on the number of executions of an algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Your first generalisation is wrong, it depends on what's the complexity of loop content. However if that 'some code' is of constant complexity [something like $O(1)$], the whole complexity will be $O(n)$.

Your second example is correct.

Answer (score 1):

heres a very nice general/introductory online ref/chapter on the subj by an expert that will answer your question and give you a firm beginning foundation, with lots of exercises.

- [Ch3. The running time of programs](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs/ch03.pdf) by Ullman.

from his book free online

- [Foundations of computer science](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs.html)

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: will sketch this out more carefully if there is more votes on your question. basically it depends on _what is inside the loop_. if it takes _constant time_ inside the loop, your reasoning is correct. if something more complicated is happening, esp function calls, which can depend on input size, it requires more sophisticated analysis...